# Is it possible to pair two bluetooth devices from a 3rd device

Tags: bluetooth

I have two bluetooth devices and I want to pair them. The one of these two is a bluetooth transmitter which sends audio to bluetooth speakers and it doesn't have any input control. the other is a bluetooth receiver which converts audio to FM radio signal. Both of them work fine with smart phone. However, the receiver need an initiator to choose its name from the list but the transmitter only support auto pairing. Is it possible to run an application on my laptop or my smartphone to initialize the pairing process for these two devices?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using some hardware like this one https://dataoverhaulers.com/connect-multiple-bluetooth-devices/. You can also try some products offered in amazon.

Comment: Not get the point of your comment. could you please detail me the steps how to pair the bluetooth transmitter and receiver?